# How to redirect a user to the Last Domain Browsed

Tags: redirection, domain-access

I have a question, what will i do to save the last domain a user was on either on a cookie or a session or anythin else that will work so that whenever they type the main domain they are redirected to the sub domain they were on last even if the browser is closed. i have about 3 sub domains and the main domain. i am using domain access. for example

main.com <== TLD
sub.main.com <== Sub Domain 1
sub2.main.com <== Sub Domain 2

user types in main.com and was browsing sub.main.com yesterday and instantly gets taken to sub.main.com
 and on another machine user types main.com and gets taken to last domain e.g. sub2.main.com
Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Cookie as Sessions will be lost once browser is closed.
You can use `hook_init()` or `hook_boot()` or `page-front.tpl.php`

```
function hook_init(){
 $domain_last_accessed = $_COOKIE['domain_cookie'];
 if($domain_last_accessed != "" && $domain_last_accessed != $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']){
 // Check if cookie is set and previous visited was not this domain then redirect
 // redirect using drupal_goto() or Header()
 }
 else{
 // Check for Cookie and set if empty, this might be the first visit or cookie was destroyed
 // SetCookie with $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]
 }
}
```

If you want it to be machine independent then you may need to store last accessed domain in DB and note that this will only help authenticated users.

Comment: it worked finally after hours of trial and error.. added a few more lines of code

Comment: Hey Let me ask. Curently. it locks a user to a subdomain or the domain that they are currently on. is there a way to browse the other subdomains and updating the cookie to the new sub domain?

Comment: Do you have a link that takes you to other sub sites ?footer perhaps ? If so then add a parameter that will unset the cookie, like sub.site.com/?nav_to_other_site=true or sub.site.com/delete_cookie and in the function check if these arguments are there if so then unset cookie.

Comment: I use a domain navigator from domain access to browse through the domains. its a drop down menu. so it has to be set everytime i browse through all the subdomains. can i do it from within the cookie?

Comment: Just add some identifier in the menu link to know that user intends to navigate to other domains, identitfer can be a get parameter or argument

Comment: ok. Tried this.. i added the cookie code to the domain list navigator coz i figured the cookie wuld be created when browsing domains and did an unset cookie in a custom module but it doesnt work. i am still locked to the domain i was browsing. expiring the cookie doesnt seem to work? do yu have some snippet for the identifier as the get argument that will allow  me to browser through the domains?

Comment: I rewrote in another format and it worked.. thanx kantu